# How to detect connection lost with Jetty WebSocket

Tags: websocket, jetty

I use a WebSocket to ensure communication between two standalone jars. The first one launches an embedded Jetty and deploys a WebSocket, and the second is the Jetty WebSocket client that sends commands and waits for the processing of the server part.

Server:

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.*;

@ClientEndpoint
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket-api", encoders = {     NotificationEncoder.class }, decoders = { NotificationDecoder.class })
public class APIWebsocket {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(APIWebsocket.class);

  @OnOpen
  public void open(Session session) {
    log.info("Session opened...");

  }

  @OnClose
  public void close(Session session) throws IOException {
    session.close();
    log.info("Session closed !");
  }

  @OnError
  public void onError(Throwable error) {
    log.error("Error during websocket session : {}", error.getMessage());
    log.debug("{}", error);
  }

  @OnMessage
  public void handleMessage(String message, Session session) {

       log.info("Message received : {}", message);

       List<Data> datas = JSONHelper.toCollection(message);
       for (Data data : datas){
          // do process with average time 30sec...
          // send notification of processing
          Notification unitNotification= new Notification("PROCESSED");
          session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(unitNotification);
       }

      // Build and send end notification message
      Notification endProcessNotification = new Notification("END OF PROCESS");
      session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(endProcessNotification);

    } catch (EncodeException | IOException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      // Manage error

    } finally {
      try {
        session.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        // Manage error
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Client:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketAdapter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient;


public class WebsocketClient extends WebSocketAdapter {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebsocketClient.class);
  private Session session = null;

  public APIWebsocketClient(String uri) {
    try {
      WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
      client.setMaxIdleTimeout(35 * 1000L);

      client.start();
      client.connect(this, new URI(uri)).get();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

  }

  public void startProcess(String datas) {
    try {
      session.getRemote().sendString(datas);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
    log.info("Message received : {}", message);
  }

  @Override
  public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
    log.info("Websocket closed ! [statusCode={}, reason={}]", statusCode, reason);
    this.session.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
    log.info("Websocket Client details : {}-{}", session.getLocalAddress().getHostName(), session
        .getLocalAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());
  }

  @Override
  public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
    log.error("Error during websocket execution : {}", cause.getMessage(), cause);

    if (this.session != null) {
      this.session.close();
    }
  }

}
```

My goal is to detect if the network communication is lost between the client and the server. If I simulate a loss of network, by disconnecting the network wire, the WebSocket should detect a communication error on both server and client side.

Do you have any idea how I could proceed to detect network loss between the client and the server?

Answer (score -1):

This is Java.

Connection lost is only detected on read/write event.
Not on physical network loss.

If you are using Android, then there are Android specific APIs for detecting network state.

Comment: The server side executes several processing and must send a state of each processing separately (You can check the updated source code of Server)

Currently, when i try to simulate a loss of network connection, the server part continues to do its processing and returns all to the resumption of the connection, if the webscoket is not yet closed.

My question is : why to the loss of connection, the event @OnError is not fired ?
When you say "This is Java", you meant that we should add our logic to handle connection loss ?

Comment: network connection loss on java is only detected when there is an actual network i/o being performed.  if the connection (and attempts at using the connection) are idle, then there is no event indicating a connection loss.